# PINAX & PIL Installation on Windows 7

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, pinax

I have Python 2.7 on Windows 7 x64.  I have installed virtualenv and installed Pinax withing the project in virtualenv.  When I try to syncdb I recieve an error stating PIL is needed.  I tried installing PIL 1.1.7 for 2.7, but it did not install correctly.  When I ran syncdb I get the following error.

```
Error: One or more models did not validate:
photologue.photo: "image": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Im
aging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .
photologue.watermark: "image": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Pytho
n Imaging Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .
avatar.avatar: "avatar": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imag
ing Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .
photos.image: "image": To use ImageFields, you need to install the Python Imagin
g Library. Get it at http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/ .
```

As I understand it is because this is a x32.  So I downloaded the unoffical x64 version from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pil and tried to install.  Windows installer states that it can not locate python so it can not install PIL.  I checked the registry and python is there.

Any thoughts because I am lost?

Comment: is your installed python an x64 version?

Comment: Are you SURE you have a 64-bit Python installed, and not a 32-bit Python? When I try and install the 64-bit version of PIL you linked, on 64-bit Windows 7 with a 32-bit Python 2.7 installed, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's been awhile since I worked on Windows, but I believe you might need to install a 64-bit version of Python. I could be wrong, but I wouldn't think that 32-bit Python would be able to run 64-bit libraries. I think the error message you are seeing is that the 64-bit PIL is looking for 64-bit Python and can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can install 32 bit PIL on Win7x64 as long as you are running 32 bit Python.